# Magento2 Model not loading complete data using Factory

Tags: magento2, controllers, model, factory

Below is my construct function of controller -

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Vendor\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Faq\CollectionFactory $faqCollectionFactory,
        \Vendor\Faq\Model\LikeFactory $faqLikeFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Vendor\Faq\Controller\Adminhtml\Faq\Save $save,
        \Vendor\Faq\Model\FaqFactory $faqModelFactory

    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->_faqModelFactory = $faqModelFactory;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->_faqLikeFactory = $faqLikeFactory;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_save = $save;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
```

And this is my execute function -

```
public function execute()
    {        

        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();         
        $_faqModel = $this->_faqModelFactory->create();
        $model = $this->_faqLikeFactory->create();         
        $getFaqData = $model->load($data['faq_id'],'faq_id')->getData(); 
        print_r($getFaqData);
        die();

}
```

The data which is getting returned in `print_r` is

```
Array
(
    [like_id] => 83
    [user_id] => 4
    [faq_id] => 3
    [like_status] => 1
)
```

But the db table has 2 rows which corresponds to the table based on faq_id

The array which is formed from `$data` is

```
Array
(
    [faq_id] => 3
    [product_id] => 275
    [like_status] => 1
)
```

Comment: Can you please explain more what your expected result?

Comment: I have shared image link of the db table. You can see load by faq_id = 3 should return 2 rows, but it is returning 1 row. I am doing some mistake there.

Comment: Image not accessible Can you please permit to access

Comment: It is not allowing me to upload image, sorry but the point is that corresponding to that faq_id I have 2 rows in db but array returns 1 row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get the answer myself.

Their were several changes needed to make it work.

1) This can not be done by `load` but by `collection`. It seems that load is used to fetch single query. I am still not sure for that but quite confident. So I was to use the collection.

2) In order to use the collection I was to make a file `Collection.php` which will reside at the location `Vendor\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Like\Collection`

3) The code of the Collection should extend to `\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection` along with the need to include the construct init with `model` and `resourceModel` of Like

4) Now inject the Collection in the construct of the controller like

```
\Vendor\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Like\Collection $likeCollectionFactory,
```

5) Then using `getCollection` fetch the data -

```
        $collection = $this->_faqLikeFactory->create()->getCollection();
        $collection = $collection->addFieldToFilter('faq_id', $data['faq_id']);
        print_r($collection->getData());
```

> If anyone has better way to get data please share your
>   answer/comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function execute()
{        

    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();         
    $collection = $this->_faqModelFactory->create()->getCollection();
    $collection = $collection->addFieldToFilter('faq_id', $data['faq_id']);

    print_r($collection->getData()); die();

}
```

Comment: Thanks but Isn't this possible by load? I want to use that method.